# Qt6 yocto build - nothing provides tslib-native

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, yocto

I'm building yocto image (core-image-minimal) on Ubuntu 18.04, default configuration and I added Qt6 to it.

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "2.2.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.1.4"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "langdale:3e95f268ce04b49ba6731fd4bbc53b1693c21963"
meta-raspberrypi     = "langdale:8e3cbfa598de106a78d9a9e27aa25ded51416896"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-networking      
meta-python          = "langdale:cbbaa82238cd60f08c9b9cb58dde59d5f9318c7b"
meta-qt6             = "6.5:a65fb409f4469c087ae3e23ee80fbb2531f1856e"
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'tslib-native' (but virtual:native:/home/martin/Downloads/yocto/build/../sources/meta-qt6/recipes-qt/qt6/qtbase_git.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
  libxi-native
  libxt-native
  zlib-native
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You could create a tslib_%.bbappend in your layer with the following line: `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"`

Comment: Alternatively you could switch to a supported yocto release. E.g. kirkstone, mickledore and nanbield have this issue fixed

Comment: Thanks a lot. After fixing this, I had a similar problem with "pointercal-naive". Fixed it the same way. Now I'm building it.